# Defining a function that takes keyword arguments and a variable number of positional ones

Tags: arguments, defun, keywords

I want to define a function that takes both keyword arguments (as in `&key`) and a variable number of positional ones (`&rest`). They should be independent of each other, the keyword list should not be part of the `&rest` variable:

```lisp
(???-defun foo (&key key &rest rest)
  (list key rest))

(foo :key 'a 1 2)
=> '(a (1 2))
```

`cl-defun` accepts both keywords, but the behavior is not what I'm looking for. The closest I got is:

```el
(cl-defun foo (&rest rest &key key &allow-other-keys)
  (list key rest))

(foo :key 'a 1 2)
=> (a (:key a 1 2))
```

Is there an idiomatic or built-in way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: `cl-defun` is what you want. AFAIK, that's the only way. Elisp `defun` does not support `&key`.